# mousePressEvent not functioning for QLabel

Tags: python, pyside2, qlabel

I read a lot of tutorials on how to get coordinates of the clicking position on an image in QLabel ("label_2" in the code below defined in "form.ui" by Qt Creator). Most of them refer to using **mousePressEvent** method. However, after implementing the method, it does not function when I click a point on the imported image. It seems that **mousePressEvent** is never called by anything. Wondering what is going wrong in it. Is there any trivial or non-trivial thing missed?

```
import sys
import os
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
from PySide2.QtCore import QFile, Qt
from PySide2.QtUiTools import QUiLoader
from PySide2.QtGui import QPixmap

class qttest(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(qttest, self).__init__()
        self.load_ui()
        self.showImage()

    def load_ui(self):
        loader = QUiLoader()
        path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "form.ui")
        ui_file = QFile(path)
        ui_file.open(QFile.ReadOnly)
        self.ui = loader.load(ui_file, self)
        ui_file.close()

    def showImage(self,file='img.jpg'):
        pixmap = QPixmap(file)
        pixmap1 = pixmap.scaled(200, 200, Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
        self.ui.label_2.setPixmap(pixmap1)
        self.ui.label_2.mousePressEvent = self.getPos

    def getPos(self,event):
        x = event.pos().x()
        y = event.pos().y()
        print(x,y)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    widget = qttest()
    widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the problem by ourselves. `self.ui = loader.load(ui_file, self)` in the code is not a recommended way to take all items in "form.ui" into consideration. By using `uic` imported from PyQt5 package, this could be solved.

Comment: Please consider this method to import "ui" file if anyone has a similar problem. https://nitratine.net/blog/post/how-to-import-a-pyqt5-ui-file-in-a-python-gui/

Comment: How do you do this with PySide instead of PyQt? I'm having the same problem. If I create a QLabel from code and assign a function to mousePressEvent, it works, but if I do the same with a QLabel loaded from a .ui file, mouse events are ignored.